# Passing Username and Password to Web Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I want to call the following [web service](https://mybusiness.expressoft.eu/webserviceintegration/v1/myshop/MyShopDataService.svc/), but would like to know how to pass a Username and Password and get a response.

Comment: r u new in iOS, in before u never worked with web service

Comment: can u show ur full web service name and what are the key values to pass

Comment: yes i m new .i work with web service but that web service don't  have credentials like that .

Comment: https://mybusiness.expressoft.eu/webserviceintegration/v1/myshop/MyShopDataService.svc/ this is the url

Comment: this is already u given in the question , i need the key values and u using in which server means .php or .net or .soap

Comment: username and password are required

Comment: i don't know which server it is.

Comment: u given this url ask him,

Comment: and the „Authorization” key from each header request must be in „Basic user:password” format. For  tests, the Username is **** and the Password **** .
For a JSON response, „Accept: application/json” must be specified in the header.

Comment: my friend only give me this he is also new  .he also provide me C# example but i cant understand i can show u that also.i will ask him more details..thanks for helping me

Comment: give 10 mins bro, i m working with payment gateway'

Comment: please pass the username/paswd in API link by using NSURLConnection.

Comment: show me the example bro how to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface ViewController ()
{ 
NSURLConnection *clearSession;
NSMutableData *receivedData;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[self clearsession];
}



-(void)clearsession

{



NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mybusiness.expressoft.eu/webserviceintegration/v1/myshop/MyShopDataService.svc/"]];




 NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=karthik&Password=abcdesg",nil];


NSLog(@" RequestString for get card details: %@",requestString);

NSMutableData *requestData =[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
clearSession = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (clearSession) {
    NSLog(@"data sent ");
} else
{
    NSLog(@"Not sent");
}

[clearSession start];


}





-(void)connection:(NSConnection*)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
if (receivedData == NULL)
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}
[receivedData setLength:0];



}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

[receivedData appendData:data];



 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
  NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
      [error localizedDescription],
      [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

UIAlertView *customAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No NetWork" message:@"Interet Connection is Lost" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[customAlert show];


}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

if (connection==clearSession)
{

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options: kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSString *tmp=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", tmp);
    NSLog(@"  parsing JSON of add checkout: %@", jsonDict);


}

}
```

Comment: try this if u not get in the answer, i hoped with u

Comment: The web service used is WCF Data Service type and uses OData protocol for addressing and updating resources. Acces is achieved through authentification header and the communication protocol (endpoint binding) is HTTP Request (webHttpBinding)

Comment: and the „Authorization” key from each header request must be in „Basic user:password” format. For  tests, the Username is  abc and the Password abc .

Comment: if change your web service is global , i try here otherwise no option to me ma

Comment: user name and password is not abc i can provide u that in separate .

Comment: change my web service global means?

Comment: i didnt get my answer